# Inserting into a MySQL database table, using C#, a string that can contain double quotes

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to insert into a MySQL database table, using C#,  a string that can contain double quotes. Here is what I've tried so far (first escaping the double quotes and then enclosing the string between double quotes):

```
string sqlStr = "INSERT INTO table(ID, Comment) VALUES ";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myDict)
{
    string id = kvp.Key;
    string comment = String.Format("\"{0}\"", kvp.Value.Replace(@"""", @"\"""));
    sqlStr +=  String.Format("({0}, {1}), ";
}
// strip last comma
sqlStr = sqlStr.Substring(0, sqlStr.Length - 2);
conn.DoSql(sqlStr);
```

But that still gives the error that I have an incorrect SQL syntax. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Use *Prepared Statements* and you won't have to care about such things anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL uses single quotes to enclose strings.  That means that double quotes in your strings don't need to be escaped, but single quotes do.  Assuming you don't have any single quotes or apostrophes in your strings, your code should read:

```
string sqlStr = "INSERT INTO table(ID, Comment) VALUES ";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myDict)
{
    string id = kvp.Key;
    string comment = String.Format("'{0}'", kvp.Value);
    sqlStr +=  String.Format("({0}, {1}), ";
}
// strip last comma
sqlStr = sqlStr.Substring(0, sqlStr.Length - 2);
conn.DoSql(sqlStr);
```

Comment: Thanks. The strings can contain single quotes as well, how would I escape those if they are present?

Comment: You double up the single quotes. Return the .Replace to the code but you're changing one single quote into a doubled up single quote.

Answer (score 0):

try to print sql statement before executing it and check it's contents

```
// firt do this
Console.WriteLine(sqlStr);

// and then this
conn.DoSql(sqlStr);
```

post contents of sqlStr if you can :)